# Discriminant of polyquadratic number fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I know that the discriminant of a biquadratic number field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt m,\sqrt n)$ is the product of the discriminants of all its quadratic subfields. This is proved by finding an integral basis of the field, find the discriminant and then compare it with the product. We can see this in Exercise $42$ chapter $2$ of *Marcus's number field*.

My question is that does this still hold true in polyquadratic extension, like $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{m_1},...,\sqrt{m_n})$ where $m_1,...,m_n$ are relatively prime? The above method cannot be applied here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This follows rather painlessly from the conductor-discriminant formula of class field theory.

Comment: Do you of any more elementary way to prove this?

Comment: Hilbert gave a formula for the discriminant of a compositum of two number fields with coprime discriminants. Use induction.

Comment: But the determinants are not always coprime here. For example if m and n are congrueng to 3 mod 4, both discriminants are divisible by 4. How do I do in this case?

Comment: You can always work out an integral basis and compute the discriminant. I think Varmon did that in his thesis "Über Abelsche Körper, deren alle Gruppeninvarianten aus einer Primzahl l bestehen und über Abelsche Körper als Kreiskörper"